# More efficient symbolic function evaluation

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

In order to perform function evaluation using normal variables one can do as follows:

```
f = @(x)x.^2+3*x-5;
x0 = -10:0.01:10;
p = f(x0);
```

But when using symbolic variables, the efficiency decreases drastically. For instance:

```
f = @(x)x.^2+3*x-5;
x0 = -10:0.001:10;

% using real values
tic;p = f(x0);toc

% using symbolic math
syms x;tic;P = double(subs(f,x,x0));toc


Elapsed time is 0.000686 seconds.
Elapsed time is 10.867689 seconds.
```

Is there a way to increase the speed while using symbols?

Comment: Symbolic variables are order of magnitudes slower than real-valued variable (i.e. anonymous functions), and that's a fact. So I'm afraid there's nothing you can do to significantly speed things up :/

Comment: If numeric computation is the end goal, I keep an extra variable around that holds a `matlabFunction` version of `f` which is used for the number crunching.

Answer (score 1):

The conversion from float to double kills the performance in this case. Never start with floating point math (`x0 = -10:0.01:10;`) and continue with symbolic math.

```
x0=sym(-10):sym(.001):sym(10);
P=double(f(x0));
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to scale vary well. For `x0 = -10:0.001:10;`, like in the OP's second example, there's barely any difference (R2015b).

Comment: @horchler: With Matlab R2013a i get much better performance. 2s for the original code vs 1/3s for the modified.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. On my machine it takes more time to execute `Elapsed time is 11.070485 seconds.` the reason is that you are using `0.01` instead of `0.001` in the question. ;)

Comment: Your first assignment to `x0` uses `0.01`, the second `0.001`, got confused by that. Was already wondering about the much better performance of the old symbolic math toolbox.

Comment: Okay, now I get 3.4s for my code and 4s for your original code. Not really an improvement.

Comment: No problem, my bad. I wanted to show the difference. That was why I used 0.001. Starting with symbolic numbers, is a good point though, tnx +1.